# How to delete a GitLab repository using curl?

Tags: git, rest, curl, gitlab, token

I am able to achieve this with GitHub. But I am unable to do the same with GitLab. Currently, what I have is:

```
curl -u "$user:$token" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN:$token" \
-X DELETE https://git.lab.com/api/v4/projects/$repo_name
```

And then I get this error:

```
curl: (35) error:14077438:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert internal error
```

I already have a working script using curl to create a GitLab repository on the command line so my curl is working fine. I just needed the delete part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Removing a project by project path

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Private-Token: $privatetoken' \
-X DELETE https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/$namespace%2F$projectname
```

- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#delete-project
- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/README.html#namespaced-path-encoding

### Possible causes for the SSL error

#### Namespaced path encoding

The URI is split by the forward slashes on the server side and then the resulting path elements are categorized.

Since the forward slash is treated as a special character, we need to [URL encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) it if we want to include it as a URI path element, so the server does not try to split it.

How this could cause a problem is more evident if you are executing a request with additional parameters behind the ID.

In the following examples `$namespace` is `foo` and `$projectname` is `bar`.

**Good**

Request: `GET /projects/foo%2Fbar/users`

URI path elements:

- `projects` - the resources the call will be executed on
- `foo%2Fbar` - the specific resource (project) name is `foo/bar` (after URL decoding it)
- `users` - the resources to return

**Bad**

Request: `GET /projects/foo/bar/users`

URI path elements:

- `projects` - the resources the call will be executed on
- `foo` - the specific resource (project) name is `foo` (no such project, namespace is missing)
- `bar` - the resource to query or action to execute (no such resource or action)
- `users` - additional query parameter (parent resource or action does not exist in the first place)

#### API endpoint

If you are using the public GitLab hosted at https://gitlab.com/, you should use the `gitlab.com` domain name instead of `git.lab.com`, the latter is not owned by GitLab Inc.

Comment: Thanks.. I have tried both `git.lab.com` and `gitlab.com`. I traced back, the main cause of all my troubles was the `%2F`  versus `/` being not exactly the same here. Care to explain why?

Comment: @ifelsemonkey I've updated my answer describing why `%2F` and `/` are not treated the same here.

Comment: Nobody should be trying `git.lab.com`. This section can be deleted from the answer.

Comment: I was unsure what the "$namespace" meant, but I found out it is the GitLab username that owns the Repository (in my case it was `root` and not (necessarily) "Administrator"), and the "$projectname" is the name of the repository. Also, with a parameterised personal access token the single quotes should be replaced with double quotes. So for me the following ended up working: `namespace="root"`,  with `projectname="foo"` and:`curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H "Private-Token: $personal_access_token" -X DELETE http://127.0.0.1/api/v4/projects/$namespace%2F$projectname`.

Comment: the example needs headers with vars double quoted

Answer (score 1):

**Removing a project by project id:**

```
curl --request DELETE --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <TOKEN>" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{
        "id": "<project_id>"}' --url "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>"
```

**Find project_id:**

```
curl --request GET --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <TOKEN>" --header "Content-Type: application/json" --url "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects"
```